# Azure Disk Encrption - Key vault secret wrap with key encryption key failed

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, bitlocker, azure-disk

When I try to enabled Azure Disk Encryption on an Azure Windows Server 2022 VM I get the following error:
*Failed to enable Azure Disk Encryption on the VM with the following exception details:Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerFailedToSendEncryptionSettingsException: The fault reason was: '  0xc142506f  RUNTIME_E_KEYVAULT_SECRET_WRAP_WITH_KEK_FAILED  Key vault secret wrap with key encryption key failed.at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.WireProtocol.WireProtocolMessage.SendEncryptionSettingsToHost()
*
I have enabled Access Policies on the KeyVault. I'm following the instructions here:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/encrypt-your-azure-vm-with-azure-disk-encryption

The KeyVault is in the same tenant as the VM.
I have JIT enabled on the VM. Not sure if that's an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of emerging issue as KEK encryption is not currently supported on Windows Server 2022.

Please try the possible 2 workarounds:

1. [Use BEK for the encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-windows#enable-encryption-on-existing-or-running-vms-with-azure-powershell)
2. Change the length of the RSA key from 2048 to the higher values

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error like below:***

> Failed to enable Azure Disk Encryption on the VM with the followingexceptiondetails:Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerFailedToSendEncryptionSettingsException:> The fault reason was: ' 0xc142506f RUNTIME_E_KEYVAULT_SECRET_WRAP_WITH_KEK_FAILED Key vault secret wrap with key encryption key failed.at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.WireProtocol.WireProtocolMessage.SendEncryptionSettingsToHost()

[image]

> **Note : Windows Server 2022 and Windows 11 do not support an RSA 2048 bit key** *Check*  [*this*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-overview).

When I created Azure Windows Server 2019 VM Azure Disk Encryption is deployed successfully like below:

[image]

When I try to check in server BitLocker drive encryption  Bitlocker is enabled in the Azure VM and the disk is encrypting successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Imran, that's great you picked up on the RSA Key Size issue. Do you think if I created the key with 4096 then it will work?

Comment: Yes, I have created the key with 4096 it's [worked](https://i.imgur.com/8oGf1KM.png).

Comment: Just re-created the key as 4096 and Azure Data Encryption worked immediately. Thank you Imran.